# Twitter status API suddenly returning error '34'

Tags: jquery, twitter

I have a script that gets the top 3 tweets from my feed. This was working just fine but now it is returning the following error in the JSON:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}
```

Twitter describes this as a classic 404 not found error, but I do not see any disruption from the API status' on the Twitter website.

Has something changed in the way we now fetch Tweets?

My code:

```
$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' + user + '&count=3&include_rts=true&callback=?', function(data) { });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong link, https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/jbrooksuk.json

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/' + user + '.json?count=3&include_rts=true&callback=?', function(data) { });
```

Comment: Bizarre! My code used to work yesterday. It's only today that this tripped up. Your answer solved the issue. Consider it ticked! Thanks.

Comment: Twitter switched off the twitter.com API endpoints yesterday. Please be aware that using api.twitter.com/1/ will only work until the beginning of next year when they want you to have moved over to 1.1 and will turn off 1 like they did today with the unversioned endpoint

Comment: thanks James ( Needed this fast ) 

@Keab42 so do you add 1.1 to your url? or is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: Adding 1.1 is the first step, but then there is something else I'm afraid. I'm still reading to work that out.

Answer (score 4):

I also found my Twitter feeds had stopped working today. It is the same problem for the links to RSS feeds.

This was working yesterday:

```
'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name='.$screenName.'&count='.$limit;
```

but now the URL has to be:

```
'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name='.$screenName.'&count='.$limit;
```

Answer (score 2):

« *If you're using any kind of "unversioned" endpoint, you'll need to move to a versioned one. Version 1 of the API is still active until March 2013. It's "version zero" of the API that is finally being removed now*. »

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10803

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11551

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happend to me for no reason. Nothing like coming back to some untouched code only to have it broken. +1 for the answer. THX

Answer (score 0):

Thanks James!
This saved not only the day, but much more!

I already implemented https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/
so the March 2013 update is already in place.

Vincent

YEL - Your Emotions Live