# SA_OAuthTwitterEngine can't post message on my timeline

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I'am using SA_OAuthTwitterEngine in my app for posting messages on my timeline. It was ok until I updated to ios6. So now it doesn't work. Here is how I login to twitter in my app delegate:

```
SA_OAuthTwitterEngine *engine;//ivar

if (self.engine == nil)
{
    self.engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
    self.engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
    self.engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;
}

UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:self.engine delegate:self];

if (controller == nil)
    return;

[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

From SA_OAuthTwitterEngine delegate method:

```
- (void)OAuthTwitterController:(SA_OAuthTwitterController *)controller authenticatedWithUsername:(NSString *)username
{
  [self.engine sendUpdate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test"]];
}
```

I try to send message to my timeline. But there is no any message in my timeline. Looking like it's ok with auth, but doesn't send a message to timeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SA_OAuthTwitterEngine is using MGTwitterEngine to do the actual Tweeting it might have stopped working. Twitter switched off some of the API endpoints that MGTwitterEngine was using.

See this question here: [Twitter status API suddenly returning error '34'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837319/twitter-status-api-suddenly-returning-error-34/12837393#comment17378795_12837393)

And doubtless many others soon to come as people realise that things have stopped working.

Comment: Hm, Just checked error, it returns:Error Domain=HTTP Code=404 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 404.)"

Comment: Yup. That sounds like it was using an endpoint that got turned off.

Comment: I found solution, it just needs to change base api. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Romula>> could u pls share the new base API dude?